# Signal not handled in PySide

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyside

I have an PySide application. In this application, the main function runs in a thread (`AnalysisThread`). In this thread, I log some stuff with the python logger. I then add a custom logger which essentially triggers a signal with a string. This signal may be handled in the main thread (the GUI thread), but obviously the slots is never triggered, but I am sure that the signal `self.messageWritten.emit` function is called (debugger confirms this). What am I doing wrong ?

```
class LogStream(QtCore.QObject):
    messageWritten = QtCore.Signal(str)
    signal_test = QtCore.Signal()

    def write(self, msg):
        if not self.signalsBlocked():
            self.messageWritten.emit(msg)


class QtHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.stream = stream

    def emit(self, record):
        record = self.format(record)
        if record:
            self.stream.write('%s\n' % record)

class AnalysisThread(QtCore.QThread):
    processing_ended = QtCore.Signal()
    processing_failed = QtCore.Signal(Exception, list)

    def __init__(self, analysis):
        super(AnalysisThread, self).__init__()
        self.analysis = analysis

    def run(self):
        try:
            process = Process(target=self.analysis.analyze)
            process.start()
            process.join()
        except Exception as err:
            exec_info = sys.exc_info()
            self.processing_failed.emit(err, exec_info)
        finally:
            self.processing_ended.emit()

class ProcessView(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ProcessView, self).__init__()
        # Log Stream
        self.stream = LogStream()
        self.stream.messageWritten.connect(self.on_log_written)

    def go(self):
        analysis = MyAnalysis()
        # Handler
        handler = QtHandler(self.stream)
        handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('(%(levelname)s-%(name)s)  %(message)s'))
        analysis.log.addHandler(handler)
        self.processing = AnalysisThread(analysis)
        self.processing.processing_ended.connect(self.on_processing_ended)

 self.processing.processing_failed.connect(self.on_processing_failed)
        self.processing.start()

    def on_log_written(self, msg):
        print('Message: {}'.format(msg))  # never called
```

**EDIT**

For clarification, it is a multithread application, but also a multiprocess one...

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working in a multithreaded environment, try specifying a **Qt.QueuedConnection** when you're hooking up your signal and slots.

For example:

```
self.stream.messageWritten.connect(self.on_log_written, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
```

Comment: According to the doc, QueuedConnection is the default behaviour for multithreading. However, it does not work, neither the DirectConnection. The log is never displayed, even at the end of execution.

Answer (score 0):

**ANSWER**

I finally found the solution. My application as noted uses multiprocessing, and the log occurs in the child process so the parent process is never alert of the signal. The solution is to create a 'link' between the child and the parent process with a `multiprocessing.Pipe`. An implementation could be

```
class Streamer(QtCore.QThread):
    messageWritten = QtCore.Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, pipe):
        super(Streamer, self).__init__()
        self.pipe = pipe

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                msg = self.pipe.recv()
            except EOFError:
                break
            else:
                self.messageWritten.emit(msg)

class QtHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, stream):
        """Instantiate handler

        :param stream: multiprocessing.Pipe
        """
        logging.Handler.__init__(self)
        self.stream = stream

    def emit(self, record):
        record = self.format(record)
        if record:
            self.stream.send('%s\n' % record)

class ProcessView(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ProcessView, self).__init__()
        # Log Stream
        mother_pipe, child_pipe = Pipe()
        self.stream = child_pipe
        self.streamer = Streamer(mother_pipe)
        self.streamer.daemon = True
        self.streamer.start()
        self.streamer.messageWritten.connect(self.on_log_written)

    def on_log_written(self, msg):
        self.ui.textBrowser_log.insertPlainText(msg)
        txt_max = self.ui.textBrowser_log.verticalScrollBar().maximum()
        self.ui.textBrowser_log.verticalScrollBar().setValue(txt_max)
```

Explanations:

The main thread (GUI) starts. At initialization, it creates a `multiprocesing.Pipe` to communicate with a child proess, and a daemon that listens to the end of the pipe. So after the child process is launched, it eventually logs something. The `QtHandler` intercepts the message and sends it through the pipe. The daemon receives the message at the other end of the pipe and forwards it to the GUI thread via the signal `messageWritten`. Finally, this signal is processed by a slot that writes it in a `QTextBrowser` which scrollbar is refreshed to